# How to update a byte buffer

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I want to know if it's possible to update a byte buffer.

Say I have the below:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(56);
buffer.putInt(12);
buffer.putLong(34);    
buffer.put(byte('A'));
```

Assuming I want to modify the buffer to say the that first int I put in should be 50, how do I do that.

I want something like:

```
public void updateByteBuffer(ByteBuffer, int position, int newValue){
  // logic to change buffer.putInt(12); to buffer.putInt(50);
  // So after this function, my ByteBuffer should contain(hex) 50,34 and 'A';
}
```

Comment: Also, no need to write a custom method for that; [`ByteBuffer` already has it builtin](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putInt-int-int-). Note though that the index is in _bytes_.

Comment: @fge buffer.put(byte('A'));   is legal in Java..you can check!!

Answer (score 2):

You could always just write [`buffer.putInt(0, 50)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putInt(int,%20int)).  That's the overload that accepts an index, as a byte offset, to indicate where to put the argument.